# GSAP MotionPath moving box along a path always ends at (0,0)

Tags: animation, gsap, pixi.js

I've got a project where I move objects around a canvas using pixi.js and GSAP.  I'm using the GSAP MotionPath plugin to move the objects along an array on `{x, y}` coords.

I noticed some of my objects would snap to (0,0) after moving along the path.

here is a codepen showing the issue.
https://codepen.io/barrard/pen/LYyqJwo

The red square snaps back to (0,0) but the yellow box remains at the end of it's path.

The paths are very similar, but I can't understand why one works, and the other doesn't.

Any help is much appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: it seems to be something related to gsap (wrong configuration, or bug etc) - not to pixi.js

Comment: observation: if i change last coordinate of red square (`[133, 41]`) to `[118, 41]` then this doesnt happen. But with `[119, 41]` (only 1 pixel difference) it happens.